# Is there a safe way to cast SQL datetimes?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Pretty simple question that I can't quite find the answer for:

Is there a simple and safe† way to cast a `varchar` to `datetime` in SQL Server?

† i.e. gracefully handle non-datetime strings with a default datetime value

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can filter your rows using the [isdate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187347.aspx) function. This query returns three rows without any conversion errors:

```
with v as (
    select '20110714' value union all
    select '2011-07-15' union all
    select '3/22/2011' union all
    select 'foo' 
)
select cast(value as datetime)
from v
where isdate(value) = 1
```

**Edit**

When you want a default vaue (like the current date/time), you could do something like this:

```
select case when isdate(value) = 1 then cast(value as datetime) else getdate() end
```

Comment: sorry your answer and my answer is identical but i didnt copy from your code.

Comment: Perfect. For others you could also "case when" it if you wanted it in-line (e.g. CASE WHEN (isdate(col) = 1) THEN convert(datetime,col) ELSE 0 END) "0" will give you 1900-01-01 so you could replace with another value (e.g. '2000-01-01') for the default value and it will be automatically converted to a datetime.

Comment: The first part of this answer is not safe. [There is no guarantee](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/537419/sql-server-should-not-raise-illogical-errors) that the `WHERE` is processed before the `project`.

Answer (score 1):

From SQL Server Denali you can use [`TRY_CONVERT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh230993%28v=SQL.110%29.aspx). A case expression is the only [safe way](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/537419/sql-server-should-not-raise-illogical-errors) in previous versions.

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
  select cast ('28/08/2006 11:23:25' as datetime)

SELECT * FROM tab_val WHERE (CASE ISDATE(val) WHEN 1 THEN CAST(val As DateTime) ELSE NULL END)
```

More details in the [manual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms187928.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

we can place a check that column have the valid datetime and if not then return nulls not genrating any error.

```
SELECT CASE ISDATE([YourDate]) WHEN 0
    THEN CAST([YourDate] AS DATETIME)
    ELSE CAST(NULL AS DATETIME) END AS [Your Date]
    FROM [dbo].[yourtable]
```